# Why ImageLoader cannot be found in volley in Android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am absolute beginner to Android. Now I am starting to use volley for Http request and image caching. So download volley.jar from this link - http://api.androidhive.info/volley/volley.jar . Then I put it inside the libs library. Then I followed a tutorial and I created a class for caching.

My image caching class

```
package com.example.newfeeds.volley;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements
        ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

But it keeps saying cannot resolve symbol ImageLoader in importing namespace.

My project structure screenshot is as follows.

[image]

I am following this tutorial. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/

Comment: May be the problem with the `jar` file. Try adding volley through `Gradle' instead of jar `compile `com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'`

Comment: It is working now. I just closed the Android studio and opened it again. It is so wired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing similar problem.
Just paste this in your build.gradle app module

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

and sync your project.

Answer (score 2):

Updated:
Just paste this in your build.gradle app module

`implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'`

and sync your project.

Answer (score 0):

I have copy pasted a project, I was also getting the same error, I rebuilt my project from build -> rebuild project and after doing some imports using "alt+enter"  the error was gone.